# check if map contains a certain value

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

Hello I am currently facing a problem or maybe I thinking too complicated.

I have a map that looks like this:

```
  std::map<int,int> mymap;
```

and I insert values doing this

```
 std::map<char,int>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
  mymap.insert (it, std::pair<int,int>(1,300));
```

now I want to find out if the map contains the value 300.

Lets assume I have a variable called input with the value 300.

```
int input = 300;
```

Now with this input I want to check whether my map has the value 300 stored in it.

I know that with map.find() I can check whether a certain key exists in a map.
But I can't use `map.find(input)` in my case because 300 isn't the key it's the value.

How can I check whether there is a value of 300 in my map?

Comment: The only way to do this would be to iterate over the entire map.

Comment: @TylerLiu then in this case my key is kind of unnecessary am I right? because I won't be needing it when iterating over the whole map

Comment: Also you can add another map that maps values to keys.

Comment: @konoha Hard to say without knowing more context. Double check that a map is really what you need instead of a list. What purpose does the key serve in this case? What is it representing?

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/search-by-value-in-a-map-in-c/amp/

Comment: @TylerLiu the amount of users. so user has input of 300 and if there were more users the map would look like this 1 300, 2 400, 3 600 etc

Comment: If you are doing this frequently [boost bimap](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html) or [boost multi index](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) might be better options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `std::find_if` to find if a value exists in a `std::map` or not shown below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
 #include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    // Create a map of three strings (that map to integers)
    std::map<int, int> m { {1, 10}, {2, 15}, {3, 300}, };
    
   int value = 300;
   auto result = std::find_if(std::begin(m), std::end(m), [value](const auto& mo) {return mo.second == value; });
 
   if(result != std::end(m))
   {
       std::cout<<"found"<<std::endl;
   }
    else 
    {
        std::cout<<"not found"<<std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output of the above program can be seen [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZNS4PqwsCSkzkmcp).